# Angular JS routing from local env

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I was going through some tutorial on Angular JS and I can load single page and do things within single file, but when I got to the routing, it would not get to the other page.

Here's what I have in the app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('tutorialApp', ["ngRoute", "tutorialCtrlModule"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "views/tutorial.html",
            controller: "TutorialCtrl"
        })
        .when("/tutorialSecond", {
            templateUrl: "views/tutorialSecond.html",
            controller: "TutorialCtrl2"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        })

})
```

and in my index.html, I include these script files:

```
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/tutorialCtrl.js"></script>
```

and just have this in the body:

```
<body>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

And in my tutorial.html, I have a link defined like this:

```
<a href="#/tutorialSecond">Tutorial Second Page</a>
```

So I can see the contents of the tutorial.html when I load my index.html.
But when I click on the "Tutorial Second Page" link, nothing happens.  And I see the URL/URI of something like this:

```
file:///<some_path>/AngularTutorial/index.html#!/#%2FtutorialSecond
```

If I change the app.js code to something like this:

```
.when("/", {
    templateUrl: "views/tutorialSecond.html",
    controller: "TutorialCtrl2"
})
```

I can see the tutorialSecond.html content show up when I load my index.html.

So why is the link to /tutorialSecond not loading from my original code when I click on the link to it?  Is it because I am running and opening the index.html as a `file://<path_to_index.html>` locally and not running on a web server?

Please help...  this is blocking me to continue with the tutorial.
I am running in Windows 7x64, using Firefox, and just downloaded the latest available angular js files yesterday.

Thank you in advance.

---

Adding some additional details per some of the responses...

In my tutorialCtrl.js file, both controllers are defined something like this:

```
angular.module("tutorialCtrlModule", [])

.controller("TutorialCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.tutorialObject = {};
    $scope.tutorialObject.title = "Main Page";
    $scope.tutorialObject.subTitle = "Sub title";
    }
}])

.controller("TutorialCtrl2", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.secondTutorial = "This is the second tutorial";
}]);
```

and this .js file is included in the index.html as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create and include script file related to tutorialCtrl2 in the index.html?

```
<script src="js/controllers/tutorialCtrl2.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've updated my question with this info, but basically a single tutorialCtrl.js defines both TutorialCtrl and TutorialCtrl2 controllers.  Please see the bottom of my question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `index.html` didn't include script `tutorialCtrl2.js` and also you can use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` to tell angular to use HTML5 strategy if available.

Here the list of browser that support HTML5 strategy: http://caniuse.com/#feat=history

Comment: I've updated my question with this info, but basically a single tutorialCtrl.js defines both TutorialCtrl and TutorialCtrl2 controllers.  Please see the bottom of my question for this.

Comment: On this locationProvider stuff.. I am guessing I update my app.js to have a line like this?
`app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {`
Then put that line you mentioned?
`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`

Comment: I probably did things wrong, but just doing what I mentioned above ends with an error and I see this in the debugging console:
`Error: [$location:nobase] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$location/nobase`

Comment: If you configure `$location` to use html5Mode, you need to specify the base URL for the application with a `<base href="">` tag or configure `$locationProvider` to not require a base tag by passing a definition object with `requireBase:false` to `$locationProvider.html5Mode():` Remember that if you want to use `$locationProvider`  you have to inject it in your `config` function

Comment: Here's an example `$locationProvider` configuration:
`$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});`